# Code Coverage with Jasmine Unittests in Magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, unit-tests

I am trying to set up the jasmine Unittests for Magento 2. I've already edited the settings.json inside the dev/tests/js/jasmine/spec_runner directory, to only test my own unit tests because I don't want to care about if unit tests of Magento or some other 3rd party modules would work or not.
So far so good, everything works fine using `grunt spec:luma`:

```
(...)
GET /pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/XXX_Osc/js/action/create-shipping-address-mock.js 200 0.611 ms - 442
GET /pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/FormData.js 200 0.386 ms - 4236
GET /pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/MutationObserver.js 200 0.431 ms - 17621
    ✓ should create
    - should create shipping address mock...
log: JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1
    ✓ should create shipping address mock

2 specs in 0.106s.
>> 0 failures
(node:14824) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.

Done.


Execution Time (2019-09-02 14:47:58 UTC+2)
loading tasks                  56ms  ▇▇▇▇▇ 4%
spec:luma                      21ms  ▇▇ 1%
connect:luma                   33ms  ▇▇▇ 2%
loading grunt-contrib-jasmine  18ms  ▇▇ 1%
jasmine:luma                   1.4s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 91%
Total 1.5s
```

but to keep care of unit tests, now I want to get code coverage output for the jasmine unit tests. I've added the grunt-template-jasmine-Istanbul (https://github.com/maenu/grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul) grunt mixin, and am trying now to change the jasmine.js in the spec_runner directory in any way to get the code coverage for the unit tests to work, but nothing of it is working so far:

Example1:

```js
tasks[themeName] = {
    src: configs,
    options: {
        host: host,
        template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul'),
        templateOptions: {
            baseUrl: baseUrl,
            coverage: 'bin/coverage/coverage.json',
            report: 'bin/coverage',
            thresholds: {
                lines: 75,
                statements: 75,
                branches: 75,
                functions: 90
            }
        },
        vendor: requireJs,
        junit: {
            path: "var/log/js-unit/",
            consolidate: true
        },

        /**
         * @todo rename "helpers" to "specs" (implies overriding grunt-contrib-jasmine code)
         */

        helpers: specs
    }
}
```

results in following console output... you may realize here that my custom js file which I want to test, is not found (404). Having a look on the var/coverage/ output it seems that it tested all the require.config.js files defined in the settings.json:

```
GET /_SpecRunner.html 200 3.716 ms - 1209
GET /.grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/jasmine.css 200 1.297 ms - 20297
GET /.grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/jasmine-html.js 200 1.857 ms - 16347
GET /.grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/jasmine.js 200 1.871 ms - 92077
GET /.grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/boot.js 200 2.171 ms - 6401
GET /.grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/json2.js 200 1.763 ms - 17569
GET /dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/XXX/Osc/view/frontend/js/action/create-shipping-address-mock.test 404 3.192 ms - 246
GET /pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js 200 3.471 ms - 82717
GET /.grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/dev/tests/js/jasmine/require.conf.js 200 2.190 ms - 1451
GET /.grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-config.js 200 2.754 ms - 40188
GET /.grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul/reporter.js 200 1.239 ms - 554
GET /.grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/reporter.js 200 1.251 ms - 3768
Warning: expected branches coverage to be at least 75% but was 40% Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

or Example2:

```js
tasks[themeName] = {
    src: configs,
    options: {
        host: host,
        template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul'),
        templateOptions: {
            baseUrl: baseUrl,
            coverage: 'bin/coverage/coverage.json',
            report: 'bin/coverage',
            thresholds: {
                lines: 75,
                statements: 75,
                branches: 75,
                functions: 90
            },
            template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs'),
            templateOptions: {
                requireConfig: {
                    baseUrl: '.grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/src/main/js/'
                }
            },
            replace: false,
        },
        vendor: requireJs,
        junit: {
            path: "var/log/js-unit/",
            consolidate: true
        },

        /**
         * @todo rename "helpers" to "specs" (implies overriding grunt-contrib-jasmine code)
         */

        helpers: specs
    }
}
```

results in:

```
GET /_SpecRunner.html 200 3.572 ms - 3961
GET /'%20+((__t%20=%20(%20style%20))%20==%20null%20?%20''%20:%20__t)%20+' 404 2.096 ms - 189
GET /'%20+((__t%20=%20(%20script%20))%20==%20null%20?%20''%20:%20__t)%20+' 404 1.515 ms - 190
GET /'%20+((__t%20=%20(%20temp%20?%20temp%20+ 404 1.588 ms - 171

Warning: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to an unfinished async spec. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```